# XSD and JAXB for sequence of repeating elements

Tags: xsd, jaxb2, xjc

I am creating a XSD to represent the following XML structure.

```
    <DETAILS>
      <REFERENCE></REFERENCE>
      <INFORMATION>
        <INFO>
            <KEY></KEY>
            <VALUE></VALUE>
            <KEY></KEY>
            <VALUE></VALUE>
            <KEY></KEY>
            <VALUE></VALUE>
            <KEY></KEY>
            <VALUE></VALUE>
            .....
        </INFO>
    </INFORMATION>
```

I intend to use the same XSD to generate JAXB annotated java classes using XJC.
I manage to get the following XSD.

```
    <xs:complexType name="DetailsType">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jaxb:class name="Details" />
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:int" name="REFERENCE">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <jaxb:property name="reference" />
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element type="InformationType" name="INFORMATION">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <jaxb:property name="Information" />
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>           
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="InformationType">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jaxb:class name="Information" />
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="INFO" type="InfoType">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <jaxb:property name="Info" />
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="InfoType">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jaxb:class name="Info" />
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="KEY" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="VALUE" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

However using this XSD, XJC generates Java classes using JAXBElement, something like,

```
    @XmlElementRefs({
    @XmlElementRef(name = "KEY", type = JAXBElement.class),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "VALUE", type = JAXBElement.class)
})
protected List<JAXBElement<String>> keysAndValues;
```

For such a trivial XML of sequence of repeating elements, the overhead of using JAXBElement seems quite annoying.
Am I missing something ?

I am open to a different approach for XSD Or can someone provide a way to tell JAXB to generate more meaningful classes (don't use JAXBElement please) ?